# creating a very simple Visual Basic code stuck on one step

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am making a very simple Visual Basic code and the problem I am getting is having the text box have wording when the program is ran.
I want the textbox to say "My name is John" and when you click the button It will then change to "and this is my first VB program". 
Also here is the code I've made:

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnClickMe_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles btnClickMe.Click

    txtOutPut.Text = "My name is John"
    txtOutPut.Text = "and this is my first VB program"

End Sub
End Class
```

Yeah sorry with the faily simple question but thanks and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your text to "My name is John" outside of the button click, perhaps in a `Form.Init` handler, then removing `txtOutPut.Text = "My name is John"` from `btnClickMe_Click1`

What's happening here is the button click is changing the text first to "My name is John", then changing it to "and this is my first VB program" and the change happens too quickly for it to be visible.

Comment: I figured it out lol. It was so easy it slipped right under my nose. I am suppose to make the text my name is john and the way to do that is by going to the textbox properties and writing in My name is John and thats it then click the button and it will say and this is my first vb program. I already had it. But thanks so much I'll be choosing your answer. in the text portion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnClickMe_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles btnClickMe.Click

    txtOutPut.Text = "My name is John" & VbCrLf & "and this is my first VB program"

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `txtOutPut.Text = "My name is John"` when the form loads (Or straight  during the design, once you place the textbox go to properties and put "My name is John" in the Text property), you have everything in the button, so when you press the button it first executes `txtOutPut.Text = "My name is John"` and then `txtOutPut.Text = "and this is my first VB program"`, and it overwrites "My name is John", so you always see "and this is my first VB program" once you pressed the button.

Comment: Thanks and yeah I just figured that out.